# Should specific information like phone numbers for individuals be allowed to be posted?

Tags: discussion, policy

I'm asking this after seeing this question: [Does anyone have the phone number for Rabbi Lionel Chiswell?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89542/does-anyone-have-the-phone-number-for-rabbi-lionel-chiswell)

A Rabbi is a public figure, but still, a brand new user asked for his phone number and it was posted.  What if the user intends to harass him?  Maybe contact information should be limited to email addresses?  The questioner could probably find a contact number elsewhere on the Web, but why make it easy for trolls and other undesirables?  Would someone be allowed to answer a new user's question "What's DoubleAA's or Monica Cellio's or YeZ's or Gary's(or anyone else here's) phone number?"  Those of us with reasons to can always put them in their Profiles.

I'm asking this because we seem to have a small number of hostile folks that don't like Jews occasionally putting up some pretty nasty stuff.  Safety first!

Answers wouldn't be allowed for questions like "I'm an alarm system specialist. Can somebody please send me a link to the blueprints of Temple XXXX's security system?"...I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am not at all commenting on whether such a question is on-topic or not; it isn't and we should discourage such questions from being asked.)

That being said, as the person that answered that question, and as I noted in the comments, I only posted what was available publicly on the Internet as a business number (and I found easily when I searched for it).  To me, that is no different than posting a question or answer from an article available online.  From a safety perspective, I don't have a problem for this, as if my business phone number is available online, by all means, let people call it.

If it would be a personal number, I would perhaps have some reservations, but again, anything that can be found by an easy Googling, and can be used to help someone here (with a positive posted purpose, at the very least), is fair game, and not a security concern.

If someone posts information that is not available easily online, or identifies someone anyonymous, I would have a major issue with that.

Comment: Gotcha, and thanks!

Comment: @Gary This is by no means authoritative, just my opinion.  Being that this is meta, if you agree with me, simply vote it up, if you disagree, downvote it.